# Jump as an alternative to RTTI

Tags: c++

I am learning how c++ is compiled into assembly and I found how exceptions works under the hood very interesting. If its okay to have more then one execution paths for exceptions why not for normal functions.

For example, lets say you have a function that can return a pointer to class A or something derived from A. The way your supposed to do it is with RTTI.

But why not, instead, have the called function, after computing the return value, jump back to the caller function into the specific location that matchs up with the return type. Like how exceptions, the execution flow can go normal or, if it throws, it lands in one of your catch handlers.

Here is my code:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int GetValue() { return 0; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int VarB;
    int GetValue() override { return VarB; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    int VarC;
    int GetValue() override { return VarC; }
};

A* Foo(int i)
{
    if(i == 1) return new B;
    if(i == 2)return new C;
    return new A;
}

void main()
{
    A* a = Foo(2);

    if(B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a))
    {
        b->VarB = 1;
    }
    else if(C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a)) // Line 36
    {
        c->VarC = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(a->GetValue() == 0);
    }
}
```

So instead of doing it with RTTI and dynamic_cast checks, why not have the Foo function just jump to the appropriate location in main. So in this case Foo returns a pointer to C, Foo should instead jump to line 36 directly.

Whats wrong with this? Why aren't people doing this? Is there a performance reason? I would think this would be cheaper then RTTI.

Or is this just a language limitation, regardless if its a good idea or not?

Comment: Please tell me why you just not learn about C++? Assembly language is diving into micro-optimisation and that has so many problems as one loses the bigger picture

Comment: To be honest needing to know the exact type of the returned pointer defeats polymorphism so it is something that you should rarely need (though sometimes unavoidable).  The *best* solution is to call a *virtual function* from the returned pointer and let the object decide what code to run.

Comment: Well maybe my example code isn't the best, but what I am wondering is why do functions only have one path. Since assembly allows us to do so much more, why doesn't c++ give us an easy way to control function return paths.

Comment: What if main calls Foo twice?

Comment: @RaymondChen I dont see a problem if it calls it multiple times with different values, the compiler should be responsible to generate the proper  assembly such that main can call as much times, with any value and Foo jumps to the proper place when it returns.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the `goto` method of programming. Functions were invented to void the kind of spaghetti code people were writing using that method. When programs get large managing the complexity becomes a real issue and is probably the main driving force behind why languages work the way they do.

Comment: I would like a tentative syntax for what you thought. All ways that I think looks very similar of the dynamic_cast case

Comment: I don't mean `main` calling `Foo` in a loop. I mean if `main` actually has two calls to `Foo`, say, one at line 30, and another one at line 60 (say). Or what if some other function calls `Foo`? How does `Foo` know which function to `goto` back to?

Comment: I didn't think that far ahead. But I still think the compiler would have enough information to figure it out. I guess one way of doing it would be to make sure any time Foo is called, there must be 3 entry points after that call (for type A*, B*, C*) then, once Foo returns,  the compiler has to generate code that would make the return jump to the corresponding entry point.

Comment: "The way your supposed to do it is with RTTI.". No, the way you're supposed to do that is via derivation and virtual functions.

Comment: "Why aren't people doing this" Because it is a bad design in aspect of OOP.  And, NO, people don't even use RTTI for this.  We should, by design, try to minimize the case that we need to distinguish the actual type and perform different logic according to actual type.

Comment: "the compiler has to generate code that would make the return jump to the corresponding entry point." This seems more work than just using the return address, especially since the complete set of functions that call `Foo` cannot be inventoried at compile time. (It isn't determined until link time.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are million different ways of defining the language. C++ is defined as it is defined. Nice or not really does not matter. If you want to improve the language, you are free to write a proposal to C++ committee. They will review it and maybe include in future standards. Sometimes this happens.

Second, although exceptions are dispatched under the hood, there are no strong reasons to think that this is more efficient comparing your handwritten code that uses RTTI. Exception dispatch still requires CPU cycles. There is no miracle there. The real difference is that for using RTTI you need to write the code yourself, while the exception dispatch code is generated for you by compiler.

You may want to call you function 10000 times and find out what will run faster: RTTI based code or exception dispatch.